# How do I configure SSH so that OTP can be used with ssh-copy-id and then only keypair authorization is accepted?

Tags: ssh

Is there a way to tell the SSH daemon, "when a remote device attempts to connect via SSH, verify against authorized_keys, but if there is no key offered, accept a one-time password so the user can use ssh-copy-id to provide it for subsequent attempts"?

**context:**
I would like to be able to set up a linux server so that a user can SSH into the box, but I want to use RSA keypairs for authentication.  I also have several devices that I want to be able to connect from, so that means providing multiple key-pairs (not a problem).

Essentially, I want to add entries to authorized_keys using OTP and ssh-copy-id, from a device that, currently would be denied access (because it hasn't presented a public key yet).  I currently have to SSH in from a machine that *can* connect, edit the sshd_config file to allow passwords, then copy over the id with a static password, turn password authentication off and reboot the daemon.  I would prefer a way to get a OTP from the system and then just use that and keep working...

Comment: You might want to write a [PAM module](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pam-to-configure-authentication-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps) for SSH that gets run if key auth fails. PAM is generally how you configure alternative auth mechanisms; that having been said, I don't know if there's already a better way out there, so I'm not giving that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Public key authentication is turned on by default and has higher priority then password authentication (handled by PAM or directly).

You can set up in `sshd_config` option `UsePAM yes` (by default on Red Hat), which will defer authentication to PAM -- this is configured in `/etc/pam.d/sshd` (can differ a bit on some systems).

For OTP you can use `google_authenticator`, or some other open implementation of one-time passwords. There are many how-to's around here. You can try to search for two-factor authentication, but basically it is adding one line like this

```
 auth            required        pam_google_authenticator.so
```

in the `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and do some configuration: Arch has nice instruction for this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Google_Authenticator

Using only one-time passwords, without the second factor can be potential risk if the one-time password or token gets lost -- I recommend you not to go this way and implement rather the two factor authentication than only one-time password.